# copy files from a ssh connected machine

Tags: ssh

I am trying to copy some files, from a computer that is located elsewhere.

Machine A connect to remote Machine B via ssh, pass a script, and this script will have to copy files from Machine B to Machine A.

I can't find a way to make this work, without open another connection to copy the files (tried rsync and scp). I would like to use the same ssh connection used to copy the script on Machine B, since I have keys that allow me to connect without password. This is to automate a process, so I need it to run without intervention.

What is the correct syntax to copy from remote machine B on machine A, using the ssh connection already open?

I can open a connection from Machine A to Machine B and run from Machine A the rsync command, but what I want is the other way: send from Machine B to Machine A, after that I ssh in Machine B.

I suspect the solution is easier than what I am thinking, but I can't really see it.

Comment: Opening another connection to run `scp` or `rsync` is the simplest solution. Why don't you want to do that?

Comment: Mostly because I shall authenticate again, open another port; I would like to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

If by writing a script your goal is to avoid having to authenticate again, consider using the ControlMaster feature of ssh, which will allow further ssh sessions to authenticate over the existing one:

http://puppetlabs.com/blog/speed-up-ssh-by-reusing-connections

Then you could use scp, sftp or rsync over ssh to retrieve the files from the remote machine as Kenster suggests.